# My GridView/ListView gets rendered only after touch in android api 18+

Tags: android, listview, gridview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

UPDATE:
My gridview / listview based on my BaseAdapter stopped working in Android 4.3. If I run it in Android 4.2 or below it works fine.

I tried it with the "dumb" getView(), that inflates a new view every time, it doesn't change a thing.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a listview and a gridview. They are 2 different graphical representations of my data. My problem goes for both, so from now on I'll only write adapterview, but it can mean both.

I set up my adapterview, with my custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. It mostly works, but sometimes when I change the settings (in a PreferenceActivity intent) and I change my dataset, call notifyDataSetChanged(), the screen doesn't get refreshed. To be more precise, some of the  items are refreshed, but the rest is kept on the screen, as they were before the change.

I read many tutorials, watched Romain Guy's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) and it seems I miss some very basic thing, but can't figure out what it is.

I added some debugging, and the strange thing is, that after I call notifyDataSetChanged(), it calls getCount(), and you can see the number has changed, and it even calls getView(), it just doesn't refresh the items on the screen. However after I touch the screen, everything is rendered (although the getView() is called again for all the visible views)

This is the beginning of my getView() function:

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView1, final ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getView(" + position + ", " + convertView1 + ", " + parent + ")");
    ViewHolder holder;
    CategoryListItemView convertView = null;
    if (convertView1 == null) {
        if (SettingsActivity.getBrowserLayout(CategoryBrowserActivity.this)) {
            convertView = (CategoryListItemView)inflator.inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            convertView = (CategoryListItemView)inflator.inflate(R.layout.category_grid_item,parent, false);
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_item_icon);
        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_browser_list_title);
        holder.featuresLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.features);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setFilter(getCategoryFilter());
        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    } else {
        convertView = (CategoryListItemView)convertView1;
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
```

The reason I cast convertView1 to CategoryListItemView is because I use it's custom functions later in getView().

My adapterview is either GridView or ListView, and the items are accordingly either category_grid_item or category_list_item, and whenever I change between the 2 visualisations I invalidate the adapter (and anyway my problem is not there)

Answer (score 2):

You have to call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() on the ui thread